# Are contacts in Skype for Business accessible via Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, skype-for-business

Just in the title. If a company is using Skype for Business with their Office 365 subscription, are the contacts in skype for business the same contacts available by the Graph API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**My understanding is currently the only way to access Skype for business data from an API standpoint is through the UCWA 2. And that the graph is not reflecting any data for S4B**. This is also why those are two different set of permissions when you declare apps in the AAD portal.

- One of the reasons behind that is probably because when using the UCWA you need to talk to different resources and endpoint for Discovery and Grant flows before getting to the data.
- Another one could be that UCWA provides streaming and some kind of notifications capabilities (status update, messages) which the graph doesn't support right now.

I really hope the S4B endpoints come to the graph at some point, things are going to be simpler.

Comment: That's kind of a bummer. Was hoping that these contact "silos" didn't exist anymore.

Comment: Hopefully Skype is going to be part of the graph sooner or later